# Level intro or intro Level?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it also possible to write "level intro" as an alternative to "intro Level"?
In case of yes, as I guess, what the grammar would be to justify the structure?

Comment: Please elaborate your question, whether it is on general topic or in any particular field.  Thx.

Comment: Defined as a relative position in a graded group, the word "level" may collocate with "intro" (which is a brief introductory passage) in no other way than via the preposition "to": Intro to Level X

Comment: See it as a phrase seen on English teaching materials and ads. Level intro, level 1, etc. The question is, while we have the structure "intro level" which is adj+n, if "level intro" can also be correct, what grammatical structure it has, if any?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it also possible to write "level intro" as an alternative to "intro
> Level"?

No. These phrases have different meanings.

1.

"intro level" refers to a particular *level*.  "Intro" means "introductory" and is an adjective that modifies "level".

intro (adjective) level (noun)

**Example**

Before taking advanced levels, you must complete the introductory level.

2.

"level intro" would be an introduction to a particular level (possibly an advanced level).

**Example**

Before taking this advanced course, you must attend the level introduction. It will describe the contents of the course and how to study it.

---

**Note**

You gave the phrases out of context. In English context is all important. It is *possible* that the two phrases could be considered to have the same meaning, but this would be unnatural grammar and the meaning would have to be forced by context.

---

---

**In reply to comments**

> Easy English Course: level intro, level 1, level 2 etc.

This is the key to why it is used. It is for *consistency*.  If you have a numbered series, it would look odd to label the books level 1, level 2, etc. but not to write level intro,

This is what can be called *catalog English"

Suppose I run a shop that sells leather goods, say belts, bags, wallets and shoes:

In my catalog, I will want to arrange the goods in alphabetical order, i.e.

**bags,
belts,
shoes,
wallets**

Then within those categories I wish to specify types, e.g.

**bags** briefcases, handbags, suitcases

**belts** cowhide, crocodile, snakeskin

**footwear** boots, court, slippers

**wallets** men, women

---

Suppose I want some boots. When searching the catalog I first go to footwear and then to boots.

Imagine what would happen if you organised the catalog differently but still in alphabetical order.

1. boots
2. briefcases
3. court shoes
4. cowhide belts
5. crocodile belts

etc.

As you can see, everything is alphabetical but the categories are mixed up. This is particularly confusing with a paper catalog but, even online, it's confusing.

---

With book titles you need to find the ***course*** first because lots of different course will have a "level 1". Then you need to find the ***level***

Comment: Chasly, basically I see your two definitions similar. Only the application differs a bit. Despite what you said, I have seen some Oxford books printing"Level intro" on their cover! Any ideas?

Comment: In what way are they similar? One uses "introductory" and the other uses "introduction". They are different parts of speech.  Do you have a picture of these books or a link to a picture?

Comment: Though grammatically different, in terms of meaning they are similar. The link is https://elt.oup.com/searchresults?fq=&q=Level+intro&cc=us&selLanguage=en

Comment: *"in terms of meaning they are similar"*. No, they aren't similar. Maybe I haven't explained well. With regard to the books, I can explain that. I'll return when I can and add to my answer. P.S. Please note that the book titles provide essential context. As I said, context makes a difference.  If you had given that context at the beginning, it would have made our task easier.

Comment: Ok many thanks! With regards to context, what if the phrase is written on a flyer giving information on available courses in a language center? Will this also make sense? E.g. Easy English Course: level intro, level 1, level 2 etc.

Comment: I've added an extra section at the end of my answer.